# How to display a message after downloading a file using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hello community I hope you can help me since I could not show a message to the user after downloading an excel file.

I am using httpRequest for sending data to the server and everything works correctly the file is downloaded but what I also want is to show the message.

Thank you very much for your help.

This is my code javaScript.

```js
function download_excel_file() {

        var file_name; //Example Test.xlsx
      
       var parameter = '{file_name:"' + file_name + '"}';
            var url = "Download.aspx/Download_File";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                var a;
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {                 
                    a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                   
                    a.download = file_name;
                    a.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    
                 // Here I want to show the message with the legend = File downloaded successfully but it does not work.
            $("[id*=message_download]").css("display","block");
            $("[id*=message_download]").text(xhr.response.Text);
                    
                }
                
            };
            
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.send(parameter);           

        

    }
```

```html
<input id="btn_download_file" type="button" value="Download file" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="return download_excel_file();"/>

 <div id="message_download" class="p-3 mb-1 bg-secondary text-white text-center" style="display:none">                                  </div>
```

This is my code from server.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void Download_File(string file_name)
    {
        if (file_name != null || file_name != "")
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Folder_Excel/" + file_name);

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                // This is the message I want to show in the div $("[id*=message_download]")
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("File downloaded successfully");                  

                System.IO.FileStream fs = null;

                fs = System.IO.File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                byte[] btFile = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(btFile, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                fs.Close();

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file_name);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(btFile);                   
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("No files");
            }
        }         
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ‘alert’ at the end of the script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("Success! File downloaded!");
}
</script>
```

---

added 2019 10 04

---

Use InnerHTML along with getElementById to set the message back from the server.

from    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Hi, I have managed to show the message with javascript on the client side but my goal was to get the text from the server side and display it as a message to further protect the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should display your message **at first**, then make the browser "click" on the download button. Otherwise the browser may just fire an `unload` event and stop executing any scripts at this time - like on redirection.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work anymore, place my message div above where the <a> tag is created and as a result I no longer download the file showing me the following error **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'blob').
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange**  can you help me?

Comment: Of course, because you are returning the *file* in your response. Probably not what you want, so you can insert your custom message instead.

Comment: Hi @Lucaz032 could you help me with the code I published please.

Comment: In general, you should not return multiple-part responses like this, because it's not going to work as expected. Please modify your **server** code to *only* return a file, then write custom success message at the **client** side, using Javascript.

Comment: Hi @Lucasz032, I have managed to show the message with javascript on the client side but my goal was to get the text from the server side and display it as a message to further protect the application.

Comment: No point to do that, since the server *already* serves you the file requested. Additional confirmations that it returns something it *actually returns* are redundant.
Also there is no "c" in my nickname :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using the **Attribute Contains Selector** correctly.

```
$("[id*=message_download]").css("display","block");
$("[id*=message_download]").text(xhr.response.Text);
```

Try this instead:

```
$("[id*='message_download']").css("display","block");
$("[id*='message_download']").text(xhr.responseText);
```

Or better yet, use `$("#message_download")`  Also notice that I changed `xhr.response.Text` to `xhr.responseText`

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work anymore, place my message div above where the <a> tag is created and as a result I no longer download the file showing me the following error **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'blob'). at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange**

Comment: Hi, I have managed to show the message with javascript on the client side but my goal was to get the text from the server side and display it as a message to further protect the application.